# Как лучше организовать структуру данных в БД?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Нужно сохранить следующие данные с анализами пациента:

- DateTime
- PatientId
- Erytr
- Tromb
- Leyk
- Hb ......и т.д.

Как лучше организовать структуру таблицы?
где поля будут, как указаны выше, либо вот так вот...?

1)

- Id  (=AnalizId)
- PatientId
- DateTime

2)

- AnalizId
- ParameterId
- Value

И как это повлияет на производительности и какие преимущества каждого типа?

Comment: Боюсь у вас другого выхода нет, кроме как хранить по второму варианту. Если конечно у вас не один вид анализов, типа общего анализа крови. Сколько у вас может проверятся различных показателей и самое главное, как часто и какова вероятность, что начнут делать какой то новый показатель ? Ради добавления каждого показателя менять структуру БД и описывать это поле в нескольких местах в программе - путь в никуда. Но первый вариант для отображения результатов конкретного анализа несомненно быстрее

Comment: И собственно почему вы предлагаете выбрать один из этих двух вариантов. Я возможно (в зависимости от стоящих задач) вообще остановился бы на хранении всех показателей конкретного анализа в одном поле в виде xml или json данных. в зависимости от того что позволяет с ними делать ваша версия СУБД. Особенно если 100% предполагаемой работы это записать данные всего анализа и выдать данные всего анализа.

Comment: У Вас есть сущности: Пациент, Анализ, Результат. Так что минимум три таблицы. А реально будет ещё больше, т.к. у первых двух сущностей есть формализуемые атрибуты.

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется второй вариант, первый вариант просто безграмотный. 
Ведь у человека анализы меняются, в больнице каждую неделю их сдают - и что вы будете стирать старые показания и вносить новые?? Должна быть полная история, в том числе и по одному показателю.

Во вторых, если у человека больная простата - ему же не будут печень исследовать? Какие-то показатели для пациента может быть вообще никогда не будут заполнены, если он не жалуется.

Answer (score -4):

Лучше конечно так
1)

- DateTime
- PatientId (id)
- Erytr
- Еще данные о пациенте

2)

- PatientId (id)
- Tromb
- Leyk
- Hb ......и т.д.
- Другие параметры анализа(этих параметров будет не больше 30 )

В твоей структуре нарушается золотое правило sql таблиц

Comment: Кто сказал что не больше 30 ? нормальные лаборатории делают анализы по сотням показателей

Comment: Такой вариант тоже не позволяет хранить историю

Comment: И вообще я не понял вашего предложения. в первой таблице вы видимо хотите хранить некие общие данные о пациенте, тогда что за поле DateTime в ней - это дата чего ? И почему у вас эритроциты оказались в первой таблице, а тромбоциты во второй ?

Comment: да затупил с тромбоцитами, Datetime дата регистрации в базе данных клиента (когда поступил), об истории ваще чтот не подумал